# Missing a record in left table when I left join with group by

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I'm looking for 14 rows and only getting 13 here.

I have 7 AGENCY_CODE in the left table and I want a row for each PROJECT_TYPE in the right table. This would be easy except there are no records of the second (Mitigation) project_type for one of the agency_codes but I need it to show up so when I split this into two tables, they are of equal sizes.

```
select i.project_type,a.agency_code,
a.agency_desc,a.sort_order,
sum(case when i.status_code='DES' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Design',
sum(case when i.status_code='ONG' then 1 else 0 end) as 'Construction'

from agencyLookup a 

left join sandy_imp_demographics i on substring(i.category,1,1)=a.agency_code 

group by i.projecT_type,a.agency_code,a.agency_desc,a.sort_order
```

You'll see it's missing Mitigation for agency_code G.

```
project_type    agency_code
Mitigation         D    
Mitigation         L    
Mitigation         M    
Mitigation         S    
Mitigation         T    
Mitigation         U    
Recovery           D    
Recovery           G    
Recovery           L    
Recovery           M    
Recovery           S    
Recovery           T    
Recovery           U
```

So what am I missing to get the null/0 rows for agency_code G?

edit: thinking about this further, this isn't a left join issue, it's a group by one.  I'm joining to agency_desc to get additional info, but the actual group fields are the problem.

```
select substring(i.category,1,1),i.project_type
from sandy_imp_demographics i
group by substring(i.category,1,1),i.project_type
```

Group A has the agency code, 7 of them, but one of them does not have a Mitigation project_type. How to I get it to show anyway, with nulls for the values I eventually pull?

EDIT: sample of table without grouping

```
(No column name)    project_type
D                 Mitigation
D                 Mitigation
D                 Mitigation
G                 Recovery
G                 Recovery
G                 Recovery
G                 Recovery
L                 Mitigation
L                 Mitigation
L                 Recovery
```

It's the G value in the first column not showing up.

Comment: Double check `substring(i.category,1,1)`

Comment: Check it for what? That's the only way to lookup the agency unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your agregation is using a column of the table in the LEFT JOIN. You have to add a case for null values.

```
select i.project_type,a.agency_code,
a.agency_desc,a.sort_order,
sum(case when i.status_code='DES' then 1 when i.status_code is null then 0 else 0 end) as 'Design',
sum(case when i.status_code='ONG' then 1 when i.status_code is null then 0 else 0 end) as 'Construction'

from agencyLookup a 

left join sandy_imp_demographics i on substring(i.category,1,1)=a.agency_code 

group by i.projecT_type,a.agency_code,a.agency_desc,a.sort_order
```

Comment: well, the else takes care of that no? Either way, adding it doesn't give me the extra row.

Comment: can you post the result of your query without grouping please ?

Comment: yup, but it's not really any different. I ended up reversing the columns when I was playing, but it's the same thing, I just felt weird selecting from the lookup table first.